# Error while Import - a lookup field value is not a lookup ID

Tags: lookup, knowledge, custom-controller, articles, data-import

I am trying to import data from .csv.
I have a field which is a lookup from custom controller.

When I import data into an object, all values from .csv are imported except lookup field values.

I am getting error:

> A lookup field value is not a lookup ID

I dont know where to get the ID from. My custom controller does not have values with any ID field.

Can anyone help me here?

Below is a screenshot of my .csv file.

[image: CSV Screenshot]

I have a controller wherein all values are present. I dont see any ID in that controller. I am new to this, so please guide me.

**Controller_C is of type "Lookup"**

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that your csv file does not have salesforce Id for lookup field. Please share screenshot of your csv.

Comment: @Nihar  I have included the screenshot and updated my question. Please help!

Comment: So, you mean this "Column D" is auto populating from the controller ?

Comment: Yes, User can select values and add to field "Controller_C". These values are coming from Controller. My requirement is : Column D should be imported from .csv.

Comment: I think you have to explicitly specify `id` for that record.  For example: `childObject.parent__r.Id`.

Comment: You mean, I should add id to my headers in .csv? How will I get the ID? Can you please guide me?

Comment: From where are you exporting the records? If you're using data loader then you can select parent's fields related to that object. And then select `id` of that parent record. You'll be done.

Comment: I am importing records. From .csv to knowledge object. There is an "Import Article" wizard under data management.